# Using RxJava with Handler reset Message.what value

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin

`Rxjava 1.1.8`

The idea is to listen to handler messages with subscriptions but `message.what` attribute comes with 0 always.

```
class RxHandler(looper: Looper) : Handler(looper) {
  val messagesObservable = PublishSubject<Message>()

  override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
    super.handleMessage(msg)
    msg?.let { messagesObservable.onNext(it) }
  }
}
```

and then subscribe to it:

```
playbackHandler.messagesObservable
          .subscribe({
              // it.what is always 0 
          }, { Timber.e(it, "Error on playback handler message handling") })
```

and then:

```
playbackHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1)
```

then I get `message.what == 0`
expected: `message.what == 1`

Comment: what is your question/problem?

Comment: @WillEvers what value is 0 but should be 1

Comment: so the problem is probably with `handleMessage` caller who gives different param value than you expect.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue! Did you ever resolve it?